# Redirect pagespeed images using rewrite back to original files

Tags: mod-rewrite, pagespeed

I have moved webservers and opted to not install mod_pagespeed on my new server.  However I am now getting lots of 404 errors on the images pagespeed rewrote.

```
logo.gif.pagespeed.ce.v58LXqGyGB.gif
```

How can i redirect these back to the original file name ?

```
logo.gif
```

I have tired the following code but without success.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.pagespeed.* -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1
```

Comment: Are the images actually stored as logo.gif or logo.gif.pagespeed...?

Comment: the image would be logo.gif in the example but I have hundreds of different names with the original images the part before the .pagespeed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.gif\.pagespeed\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?\.gif)\..*\.gif$ $1 [NC,L]
```